# ActiveRecord performance optimization

Tags: mysql, activerecord, query-optimization

I have an ActiveRecord query that is sometimes taking up to a minute to complete. I'm trying to find ways to optimize it but unsure where to start with it.

I have the following code:

```
UserPlacement.notified.select('COUNT(responded_at) / COUNT(*)')
```

which translates to:

```
SELECT Count(responded_at) / Count(*)
FROM   `user_placements`
WHERE  `user_placements`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       AND ( `user_placements`.`notification_sent` IS NOT NULL )
       AND `user_placements`.`user_id` = 1
```

the `user_placements` table indexes:

```
index_user_p_campaign_unique, ["placement_campaign_id", "user_id"]
fk__user_placements_tuser_id, ["user_id"]
```

What steps should I go through to analyze and increase performance of this query?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not sufficient:

```
INDEX(user_id)
```

you can get some better performance by having a "covering index":

```
INDEX(deleted_at, user_id, notification_sent, responded_at)
```